# Flash : How to write roll over coding for grid in array which is similar colour movieclips nearby?

Tags: iphone, actionscript-3, flash, ipad, actionscript

Flash AS3:
           I just need to know how to check a condition for roll over effect on similar colour movieclips which is near by  in a group of random colours movieclips in a grid whereas it is using 2D Array in flash AS3.or
        I just need roll over event which i wrote is onBoxOver event function, in that the object which i am targetting is only getting rollover or getting alpha changes. But i need to know how to make rollover for similar colour which are all nearby.

```
    The code which i wrote is below for your reference.
```

Flash AS3::

```
package 
{
    import flash.display.MovieClip;
        import flash.events.MouseEvent;

        public class playGame extends MovieClip
        {
            public static var totalRowBoxes:Number = 13;
            public static var totalColumnBoxes:Number = 12;
            public static var rowGap:Number = 30;
            public static var columnGap:Number = 30;
            public static var totalColorBoxes:Number = 8;
            public static var boxCollection:Array = new Array();
            public static var boxCollection1:Array = new Array();

            public function playGame(theGame:main)
            {
                // constructor code
                addBoxOnStage();
            }

            private function addBoxOnStage():void
            {
            var borderCont:Banner = new Banner();
                var scoreclipCont:scoreclip = new scoreclip();
                addChild(borderCont);
                addChild(scoreclipCont);
                scoreclipCont.x = 0;
                scoreclipCont.y = 0;
                createLevel(1);

                for (var i:Number = 0; i<totalRowBoxes; i++)
                {
                    boxCollection[i] = new Array(i);
                    for (var j:Number = 0; j<totalColumnBoxes; j++)
                    {
                        var squareCont:square = new square();
                        squareCont.x = 30 + (i * rowGap);
                        squareCont.y = 30 + (j * columnGap);
                        squareCont.name = i + "_" + j;
                        var boxCollection1:Array = new Array();
                        boxCollection1[0] = Math.round(Math.random() * 8);
                        boxCollection1[1] = squareCont;
                        var boxColour:Number = new Number();
                        boxColour = boxCollection1[0];
                        boxCollection[i][j] = boxCollection1[1];
                        addChild(squareCont);
                        squareCont.gotoAndStop(boxCollection1[0]);
                        squareCont.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, onBoxOver);                       squareCont.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT, onBoxOut);
                               squareCont.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onBoxClick);
                        }
                }
                }

            private function onBoxClick(eve:MouseEvent):void
            {

            }

            private function onBoxOver(eve:MouseEvent):void
            {
                for (var i:Number=0; i< totalRowBoxes; i++)
                {
                    for (var j:Number=0; j<totalColumnBoxes; j++)
                    {
                        eve.target.alpha = 0.3;
                        // trace(boxCollection[i][j].currentFrame)
                        trace(eve.target);
                    }

        }
            }

            private function onBoxOut(eve:MouseEvent):void
            {
                eve.target.alpha = 1;
            }

            private function createLevel(lvl):void
            {

            }


        }
       }


   ![My Game screenshot here colourbox][1]

    Thanks in Advance. Greatly Appreciable for the reply.
```

Hi this is the image or screenshot of my project. In that image there are 8 colours randomly arranged. whenever i make mouse position or  rollover on any box , the condition should check whether the same colour occurs around the box(eg.top, down, left, right) which i am making rollover.
1.If the same colour occur on the top of the box which i am pointing the cursor , the top box and the box which i am pointing both should get less alpha, else only the pointing box should get less alpha. this is my concept friends. please go through the image and let me know if u have any doubts.

Comment: When you refer to 'nearby' items, do you mean adjacent? How do you define 'similar' colour?

Comment: I just don't know how to define the rollover effect for the similar colours which are all on nearby. onBoxOver function i need to get a rollover effect (or) the box alpha should get less when i am rolling over the mouse over the box and also if the same colour locates nearby the box which i am getting rollOver those same colour boxes also should get less alpha, this is my concept mfa . If you don't have problem please let me know your mailID please i will send my project details mr.mfa. And this is my mail id: srisivad27@gmail.com please feel free to get in touch Mr.mfa

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am still unsure what you mean by 'nearby'. (neighbour tiles? adjacent of similar colour?...)
If 'nearby' means adjacent, you need to read about flood fill algorithms. [There is a good wiki article about this.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flood_fill) You would use that to crawl through the list of tiles similar enough to trigger the effect you want.

I also don't know what 'similar' colour means in your project. You will need a method to determine weather two colours are similar. There is a stackoverflow question re: similar colour detection. It has a good answer to start you out in your research. [look here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5347867/color-detection-algorithm-how-should-i-do-this)

Comment: sry mr.mfa i didn't get the right solution for my problem. If you don't have problem please let me know your mailID please i will send my project details mr.mfa. And this is my mail id: srisivad27@gmail.com please feel free to get in touch Mr.mfa... Hi mr mfa. i have edited my question above and the description have been added again. please go through the description above which i have added new in down.And also this is the link of my screenshot image which describes cool .. i.stack.imgur.com/Pwxk5.jpg plese go through this and let me know whether you could understand are not.?